# REST API GET FIELDS IN ARRAY

Tags: rest-api, execute-anonymous

Hello guys i want to get Json array in fields,

I created 1 php file in a server and this php file to bring JSON data for the Product Informations, And after i wrote 1 apex code in Execute Anonymous and this code inside i want to get my fields but i couldnt reach,

As my following example

```
try 
{
        Http http = new Http();
        HttpRequest RequestProductList = new HttpRequest();
        RequestProductList.setEndPoint('388.221.34.12/ProductList.php');
        RequestProductList.setMethod('GET');
        RequestProductList.setTimeOut(120000);
        RequestProductList.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
        HttpResponse ResponseProductList = http.send(RequestProductList);

        if (ResponseProductList.getStatusCode() == 200)
        {

            Map<String,Object> results = (Map<String,Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(ResponseProductList.getBody());
            Map<String,Object> data = (Map<String,Object>) results.get('data');
            List<Object> Products = (List<Object>) data.get('productList');
            for(Object Prd: Products){
                system.debug(Products(Prd['AverageInventory'])); 
                ***ErrorMessage: Expression must be a list type: Object***
                   How can i get this AverageInventory field ? or others,

            }
        }
}
catch (exception ex){
    system.debug(ex);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Product` again will be in the form of Map. So, you need to type-cast it to map and then get the field value:

```
for(Object Prd: Products){
       Map<String, Object> prdObject = (Map<String, Object>) Prd;
       System.debug('prdObject => '+prdObject);
       Integer AverageInventory = prdObject.containsKey('AverageInventory') : (Integer) prdObject.get('AverageInventory') : null; // OR Integer.valueOf(prdObject.get('AverageInventory'));
       System.debug('AverageInventory => '+AverageInventory);
       String MyStringField = prdObject.containsKey('MyStringField') : (String) prdObject.get('MyStringField') : null; // OR String.valueOf(prdObject.get('MyStringField'));
       System.debug('MyStringField => '+MyStringField);
   }
```

Comment: Firstly thanks for your answer i tried but now i get error message from to catch System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object

Comment: That could be because you may not have the property you need. You can use containsKey for checking that. Also better to debug the prdObject and check for exact properties APIs.

Comment: updated answer with code

Comment: Yes ! its worked thanks for your answer :)))) and so thanks to you in this case i can check null fields :D